# ZXing under iOS does not run in emulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, qr-code, zxing

I was just trying to run the ScanTest from ZXing on Xcode just to see if the code works. The project compiles without any error, but it does not run in the emulator (5.1). I just took the code directly from the ZXing repository, without any modifications.

What is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any camera on iOS simulator so ZXing can't run.

Use a real device with a camera.